# list of nested dictionary to multiindex pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a query to Tableau back in the form of a list of nested dictionaries, with lists inside of the values. I'm wondering if it's possible to blow this out in a general way.

I'm trying to turn this

```py
r = [{'name': 'TestWorkbook',
  'embeddedDatasources': [{'name': 'Test1', 'id':'uuid1'},
   {'name': 'Test2', 'id': 'uuid2'}],
  'upstreamDatasources': [{'name': 'Test1', 'id': 'uuid1'}]},
 {'name': 'TestWorkbook2',
  'embeddedDatasources': [{'name': 'OtherTest', 'id': 'uuid3'}],
  'upstreamDatasources': []}]
```

into

```py
pd.DataFrame({('name', 'name'):['TestWorkbook', 'TestWorkbook', 'TestWorkbook2'], 
    ('embeddedDatasources', 'name'): ['Test1', 'Test2', 'OtherTest'], 
    ('embeddedDatasources', 'id'): ['uuid1', 'uuid2', 'uuid3'], 
    ('upstreamDatasources', 'name'): ['Test1', None, None], 
    ('upstreamDatasources', 'id'): ['uuid1', None, None], 
})
```

I can do it brute force but I have to do it for every query I give that I want.  (The name/name bit is simply because it doesn't have multiple levels).  Even if there was a step that would get me 80% there, I would love.

*Edit* pretty sure what I'm looking for is `pd.json_normalize` but will update with actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you wanted, but it may be a good starting place~

```
r = [{'name': 'TestWorkbook',
  'embeddedDatasources': [{'name': 'Test1', 'id':'uuid1'},
   {'name': 'Test2', 'id': 'uuid2'}],
  'upstreamDatasources': [{'name': 'Test1', 'id': 'uuid1'}]},
 {'name': 'TestWorkbook2',
  'embeddedDatasources': [{'name': 'OtherTest', 'id': 'uuid3'}],
  'upstreamDatasources': []}]

sources = ['upstreamDatasources', 'embeddedDatasources']

dfs = []
for source in sources:
    df = pd.json_normalize(r, [source], ['name'], 'workbook_')
    df['source'] = source
    df = df.pivot(columns=['workbook_name', 'id'], index='source').T
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(-3, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
source              upstreamDatasources embeddedDatasources
workbook_name id
TestWorkbook  uuid1               Test1                 NaN
              uuid1                 NaN               Test1
              uuid2                 NaN               Test2
TestWorkbook2 uuid3                 NaN           OtherTest
```